# How do I keep the line at the end of a input prompt?

Tags: python, input, prompt

I was curious on how to keep the line input at the end of the question asked. My professor said I can add the `end = ""` parameter after the first parameter but I am getting an unexpected keyword argument with it.

TypeError: input() got an unexpected keyword argument 'end'

Here is the code I am trying to have the "cursor input" stay at the end of the question instead of shifting back to the line start.

```
    str1 = input("Please enter letters to encrypt:", end = "")
    num = int(input("Enter a numerical value:", end = ""))
```

Any input would be appreciated. No pun intended :)

Comment: Did you try it without the `end = ''` bit?  It seems to me like that should have worked...

Comment: Ahh thank you. Not sure why he is asking us to use the end = "" parameter. I suppose I don't understand it fully. Thank you.

Comment: `end` is a valid argument for the `print` function, there may have been a little confusion

Comment: In python2.x, `raw_input` does not add a newline after the prompt.  Not sure about how this has changed in python 3.x with the renaming of `raw_input` to `input`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `end` is a valid argument for `input()`. It's only for `print()`

**print("write something", end="")** is **valid**.

**input("Ask for user input", end="")** is **not** valid.